# How to switch between many databases without having to manually execute lots of USE DB queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a `PHP` script that reads and writes from multiple databases.  I am using the `mysqli` extension.  I connect to servers like this:

```
$link = new mysqli( $host, $user, $passwd );
```

The problem is that in my code I have to keep doing this when I want to read/write from a different database:

```
$this->link->select_db( 'some_db' );
```

but it's a pain having to remember to select the DB before using it.

I could do this:

```
$link1 = new mysqli( $host, $user, $passwd, $db1 );
$link2 = new mysqli( $host, $user, $passwd, $db2 );
...
...
```

but why make many connections to a host when I should only need one?  Even though there are multiple DBs.

Is there a way you're meant to do this?

Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2-part object names?

```
SELECT * FROM db1.SomeTable;
CALL db2.SomeProc();
```